# How to load modules which assume different baseUrl

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a file structure which looks like this:

```
/js
 |-module/myModule.js
 |-test.js
/vendor/
/spec
 |-main.js
 |-js/app.js
```

---

`spec/main.js` is my entry point and from it I load modules in `/js,`  `/vendor`, `/spec`

I have no problem to load modules which are in `vendor` and in `spec` because these modules are built assuming `baseUrl = '/'`.

I have a problem when loading modules in `/js` because these modules are built assuming that `baseUrl = '/js'`.

How can I fix this issue without changing the code of scripts in `'/js'` ?

Here's an example with comments inline describing the problem.

---

**spec/main.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    require.config({
        baseUrl: '../'
    });
});

define([
    'spec/js/app' // it works
], function (app) {
    'use strict';
    app.initialize();
});
```

---

**spec/js/app.js**

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    define([
        'js/module/myModule' // it works
    ], function () {
     // some code
    });
});
```

---

**js/module/myModule.js**

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    define([
        'test' // it does not works because
               // it assumes that baseUrl equals '/js' and not '/'
    ], function () {
     // some code
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I am missing all the () in the annonymous functions which are wrapping your code.

For example, in this piece of code:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    require.config({
        baseUrl: '../'
    });
}()); // <-- missing ()
```

Basically, this piece of code is doing nothing since is not being executed. When you wrap your code inside an anonymous function (to avoid polluting global scope, to make your code easier to minimized, ...) you have to execute it!  But probably it's a typo when you wrote this post.

I have a couple of solutions, but I'm afraid they don't resolve your problem easily or in 100% of the case (I'm not saying there isn't that solution, I'm just saying I don't know it)

First is you can define *paths* in the require.config object something like:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '../',
        paths : {
            test : 'js/test.js'
    }
});
```

And with that your code will work. I'm aware is no the best solution since you would have to define an entry in the path for every single file and I guess your're looking for a more generic solution.

With path you could always set in the dependencies of one package (one group of modules) a *prefix*, so you can organize your code in packages and in any dependency to that module add the prefix. And if the package has a main file, you can add the path to the require.config on demand the PREFFIX to link to the path to the current location of that module.

Another solution I could think of is to use relative paths in your modules inside js. If you encounter this problem very often, maybe you should define from now one your modules' dependencies always using relative paths. So

```
define([
        'test'
    ], function () {
        ...
);
```

would become:

```
define([
        '../test'
    ], function () {
        ...
);
```

But, since I can't think in any real solution for your problem (to solve this without changing anything in the code of your js/ files), I would suggest to start using relative paths in the dependencies of your packages, if you are used to reuse group of modules among different projects. And of course, organize the files in a certain way.

Let's see if somebody has a real solution for your problem.